# Image Tile Gen: OutOfMemory

Tags: c#, image, garbage-collection, out-of-memory

I'm attempting to write a program that will chop up a png file based on a dimension supplied by the user. I finally have the program working to an extent, however it will only generate 3 images before giving me an OutOfMemory exception.

I've tried setting the `Bitmap` to `Null`, calling `.Dispose()`, using `GC.Collect()`, `GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers()`

I just can't seem to free up the resources to continue my for loop.

```
    public void ChopSheet(int dim, Bitmap image)
    {
        try
        {
            int x_Max = image.Size.Width;
            int y_Max = image.Size.Height;

            Point[,] Tiles = GetTiles(x_Max, y_Max, dim);

            int xPosition = 0;
            int yPosition = 0;

            sfd.Filter = "PNG | *.png";
            sfd.ShowDialog();
            output = sfd.FileName;

            int numb=0;
            //Gen columns then drop to next row
            for (int r = 0; r <= tiles_Y; r++)
            {
                for (int c = 0; c <= tiles_X; c++) // extract images
                {
                    //cropped = null;

                    numb = c + r;
                    MessageBox.Show("making tile #" + (numb));
                    srcRect.X = xPosition;
                    srcRect.Y = yPosition;

                    srcRect.Width = Tiles[r, c].X;
                    srcRect.Height = Tiles[r, c].Y;

                    cropped = image.Clone(srcRect, image.PixelFormat);

                    xPosition += dim;

                    sb = new StringBuilder(output);
                    if (numb == 0)
                        output = sb.Insert(sb.Length - 4, "_" + numb).ToString();
                    else if (numb > 0)
                        output = sb.Replace("_" + (numb - 1), "_" + numb).ToString();


                    if (output != "")
                        cropped.Save(output);

                    //freeup memory.. somehow
                    //cropped.Dispose();
                }

                xPosition = 0;
                yPosition += dim;
            }
        }//end Try block
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
        }//end catch
    }
```

Comment: Which line throws the exception

Comment: My first guess would be that you're miscalculating your tiles and asking for a rectangle beyond the bounds of the image. That's [documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141944.aspx) to throw an `OutOfMemoryException`. Of course, you've not shown the code that calculates the tiles so this is just a guess at this stage.

Comment: So far as i can tell it's no specific line, when it tries to enter the encapsulated for loop for a 3rd time it crashes out then displays "Error: Out of Memory".

Comment: @Damien my code that sets up the dimensions is quite lengthy(I'll add it if asked again). but it is set up to only be within the constraints of the image size.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, you sir have given me the 1st clue, yes somewhere i flipped my Width and height values, now just gotta track down where, THANKS!